# Ngx-Bootstrap modal not refreshing data changes if shown from subscription

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a modal from component and I'm calling the show method in response to another subscription if call it outside the subscription it works fine. But from subscription, the data passed to content is not being refreshed Below is an example of the code.

```
//Subscription
$subject.subscribe(res => {
  const bs_modal = this._bsModalService.show(ComponentA);
  bs_modal.content.data = res;

  this._bsModalService.onHide.subscribe(() => {
     console.log(bs_modal.content.res_data));
  })

})

// Modal Component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  template: `
     <div>{{data | json}}<div>
     <button (click)="hideModal()">Hide Me</button>
  `,
})

class ComponentA {
  data: any;
  res_data: any;
  constructor(_bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {}

  hideModal() {
    this.res_data = 'Testing';
    this._bsModalRef.hide();
  }
}
```

On Modal Open the `data` is empty and whenever I close modal the `res_data` is also undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated your code in a stackblitz and I am able to pass data into the modal after tweaking a few things: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-37iw9w

Ensure these things:

- You have exported componentA class.
- You have imported ModalModule.forRoot() in your module.
- You have added componentA to the declarations array in your module.
- You have added componentA to entryComponents array in your module.

This is under the presumption, based on the code samples you have given, that they are belong in one module.

Comment: I have ensured all the above points, and yes they belong to one module

Comment: Is the code in my stackblitz not working for you too? Sorry my English is kinda weak. I have edited my answer in case you thought I had only created the stackblitz with your code in it.

Comment: I'd suggest copy and pasting bit by bit from the stackblitz into your code, and see if it'd work for you too. You might have just missed one tiny thing which caused it not to work. Also remember to check your browser console for any errors, and post it here if you aren't able to resolve it yourself.